# Discord Bot Take User's Text and Post it

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am looking for a discord bot made in .py that does those 3 things:

1. post to a specific channel
2. whatever user writes then bot deletes it and post it
3. information of who wrote what in another specific channel. example:
   {user} wrote `Hi my name is Nick`

Thanks in advance! I have not tried something yet, because I am not that experienced. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what bot library are you using? did you try the examples?

Comment: We are not here to do the work for you. You have to try yourself first by looking at documentations and tutorials.

Comment: StackOverFlow isn't a place for people to do work for you. Go jump into some youtube tutorials, and if you run into problems along the way feel free to ask here. The link here will help explain what kind of questions are on topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='prefix')


@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, arg):
    message = ctx.message # Get your message
    await channel.send(f"{ctx.author}: {arg}") # Send your message
    await message.delete() # Delete user message


bot.run('token')
```